# text-decoration: none; is not working when the parent element is displayed as flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why does my **`text-decoration: none;`** not work when the parent element contains
`display: flex; text-decoration: line-through;`

How can I fix this problem?

I have a sample  [**here**](https://codepen.io/Zaher-aa/pen/porjVNL) pen on codepen.

```
<div class="parent">
    <button>Click</button>
</div>
```

```
.parent {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* Why this code does not work ?????? */
.parent button {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

When putting `text-decoration: line-through` on the parent element, you are actually making a line through the whole element, but it will only show in places where it can attach itself to content. So you can never overwrite this line, by trying to remove it from the child elements, since it's not directly related to them.

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Ok, but how can I fix this problem?